# Snapping all clips together in Adobe Premiere

Tags: premiere

Usually when I speed up a set of clips, their duration changes in the timeline.
[image]

Is there a quick way to snap them all together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a recent version of Premiere you can use the close gaps function, found in  **Sequence > Close Gap**.

For previous versions (pre 2018), try the method in this video: [Deleting multiple Gaps in Premiere Pro all at once](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I89jYuZYvP8), where you add a matte layer, then drag the existing clips over it to cut it into chunks where the gaps are, then ripple delete it. Works in any version of PP.